# Which is the best way to write this scala method?

Tags: scala

Judge it from the perspective of writing idiomatic code, efficient code etc.

I have multiple ways defined below get the conf value from getConf1, getConf2, or getConf3 whichever successfully yields a value first when invoked in that order. In other words if getConf1 yields a value we will skip the remaining two. If getConf1 does not yield a value then we will try getConf2 and so on.

```
def getConf1(name: String): Option[String]

def getConf2(name: String): Option[String]

def getConf3(name: String): Option[String]
```

Approach 1:

```
def getSetting(name: String): Option[String] = {
    var r = getConf1(name)
    if(!r.isDefined) { 
        r = getConf2(name)
    }
    if(!r.isDefined) { 
        r  getConf3(name)
    }
    r 

}
```

Approach 2:

```
def getSetting(name: String): Option[String] = {
    val val1 = getConf1(name)
    val val2 = getConf2(name)
    val val3 = getConf3(name)

   (val1, val2, val3) match {
             case (a: Some[String], _, _) => a
             case (_, a: Some[String], _) => a
             case (_, _, a: Some[String]) => a
             case _ => None
   }
}
```

Approach 3:

```
def getSetting(name: String): Option[String] = {
 val myList = List( 
    (n:String) => getVal1(n),
    (n:String) => getVal2(n),
    (n:String) => getVal3(n))

doConditionally(name, myList)
```

}

```
def doConditionally[T1, T2](name: T1,  list: List[(T1) => Option[T2]]): Option[T2] = { 
    list match {
      case h::t => 
           val r = h(name)
           if(r.isEmpty) { 
              doConditionally(name, t)
           } else { 
             r
           }
      case Nil =>
        None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chain with `orElse`:

```
getConf1(name).orElse(getConf2(name)).orElse(getConf3(name))
```

Note that `getConf2` and `getConf3` will *only* be called if the chain is `None` when it reaches them (they're lazily evaluated).

Comment: You mean `getConf1(name) orElse getConf2(name) orElse getConf3(name)`.

Comment: I am going to say: Beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

A side note, to find the first function that delivers a value,

```
Seq(getConf1 _, getConf2 _, getConf3 _).find(_("aName").isDefined)
```